# Are generated id's unique per entity or for my app's complete datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I'm using

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

in my JPA Entities to let Google AppEngine generate id's for my entities.
Now I wonder if the generated a unique per entity or for my app's complete datastore.

The reason I'm asking is I want to use the entity's id as identifier for search documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [per docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#allocateIds%28java.lang.String,%20long%29): `IDs are allocated within a namespace defined by a parent key and a kind`

Comment: ok thanks, that means I can't use the directly as id for search documents. will need to prefix them with kind probably.

Comment: You can use `DatastoreService.allocateIds("yourmadeupkind", 1)`. This will return one generated unique ID. The kind, "yourmadeupkind" must be always the same - you should not change it during lifetime of the app or it might start generating duplicate IDs.